# Mule consuming JMS topic message

Tags: mule

My flow is:

```
 <flow name="activemqFlow3" doc:name="activemqFlow3">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${hostname}" port="${port}" path="producetopic"  doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <set-payload value="===TOPIC===" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <jms:outbound-endpoint topic="sfdc" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS"  />
    </flow>
    <flow name="activemqFlow4" doc:name="activemqFlow4">
        <jms:inbound-endpoint doc:name="JMS" connector-ref="Active_MQ" topic="sfdc"/>
        <logger message="===#[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
```

AcitveMQ console shows one consumer under topic section, but I dont receive immediate response in the anypoint studio console once hit the http://localhost:9001/producetopic url. When I go to AcitveMQ console http://localhost:8161/admin/topics.jsp and selecting sfdc topic, send button will get the response in the Anypoint studio console.
Why immediate response/subscribe not displaying  when I publish topic?

> **EDIT**

Global element:

```
<jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ"/>
```

Console:

```
INFO  2015-05-15 07:56:21,820 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Mule is up and kicking (every 5000ms)                    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
INFO  2015-05-15 07:56:29,081 [[sfdc].activemqFlow4.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: ======TOPIC===
```

Comment: Can you add the code of your jsm connector configuration?

Comment: Any error reported by `activemqFlow3`? What HTTP response do you get?

Comment: @DavidDossot, added console logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake, server was displaying the data in the console. To understand better I have modified the subscriber logger to differentiate data from publisher.

```
<logger message="==Subscriber=#[message.payload]====" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Now the console displays:

```
 ==Subscriber====TOPIC=======
```

Comment: What server? ActiveMQ or Mule?

Comment: @DavidDossot, updated answer above :). was nothing wrong in server